# Redirect on ngOnInit Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, ngoninit

I'm trying to redirect my app when launching and it's not working. I'm just trying to use router.navigate in my ngOnInit() and it returns false.

I tried to insert it in a setTimeout and then it works.

If you have any idea it would be appreciated :)

```
ngOnInit() {

    // On redirige au lancement sur la page hors connexion
    setTimeout(() => this._router.navigate(["/hors-connexion"]));

}
```

Comment: add code for more information.

Comment: It's done micronyks :)

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Ok I'm creating a new project to reproduce with just that piece of code.

Comment: I used redirectTo /hors-connexion on the default route instead of redirecting when launching! It works thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like this:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'test-component',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})

export class TestComponent {

    constructor(
        public router: Router
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.router.navigate(['hors-connexion']);
    }
}
```